# get current datetime in minutes and convert datetime (d.m.Y H:m) to minutes Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datetime-format, date-difference

Please i need some help in **javascript or jQuery** :

how to get **current** date and time to **minutes**?

i have a datetime in that format : `'d/m/Y H:m'` (example `25/12/2016 22:35`) in input . how to **get** it and convert it to minutes ? and make difference between it and current datetime

Thank you in advance for help. I tried all but nothing works

Comment: check this http://momentjs.com/

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: [`new Date().getTime()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getTime.asp)

Comment: i post a answer and what i did , i tried multiple times , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current date and time to minutes, you could divide the milliseconds:

```
var theMinutes = new Date().getTime() / (1000 * 60);
```

To get the input and convert it to minutes, you could use a Date object, and divide the milliseconds:

```
    var someDateTime = document.getElementById("someDateTime").value;
var someParts = someDateTime.split(" ");
var theDate = someParts[0];
var theTime = someParts[1];
var dateParts = theDate.split("/");
var timeParts = theTime.split(":");
var theDay = dateParts[0];
var theMonth = dateParts[1];
var theYear = dateParts[2];
var theHours = timeParts[0];
var theMinutes = timeParts[1];
var someDateTimeObject = new Date(theYear, theMonth, theDay, theHours, theMinutes, 0 );
var someDateTimeObjectMillis = someDateTimeObject.getTime();
var someDateTimeObjectMinutes = someDateTimeObjectMillis / (1000 * 60);
```

Comment: Just so you know, [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) does the same thing as `new Date().getTime()`. It has pretty good browser support, IE9+ and fairly old versions of the other browsers.

Comment: Thank you that helped me much

Answer (score 0):

Hello thank you for all yours answers

Firsly i get the current time using php ( in Milliseconds)  then convert pickup date to milliseconds and get differences between them in hours :
promo (in minutes) i get  767 hours normally i should get : 47 hours and some minutes

```
 var startdate=document.getElementById('pickupdate').value; //03-11-2015 15:49


var someParts = startdate.split(" ");
var theDate = someParts[0];
var theTime = someParts[1];
var dateParts = theDate.split("-");
var timeParts = theTime.split(":");
var theDay = dateParts[0];
var theMonth = dateParts[1];
var theYear = dateParts[2];
var theHours = timeParts[0];
var theMinutes = timeParts[1];
var someDateTimeObject = new Date(theYear, theMonth, theDay, theHours, theMinutes, 0 );
var someDateTimeObjectMillis = someDateTimeObject.getTime();
//var someDateTimeObjectMinutes = someDateTimeObjectMillis / (1000 * 60);


alert(someDateTimeObjectMillis);
var maintenant = <?php echo(round(microtime(true) * 1000)); ?>;
alert(maintenant);
var diff = someDateTimeObjectMillis - maintenant;
alert(diff);

var promo = diff/(60 * 1000);
alert(promo); // 46079
```

thank you for your support